# divergence of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let f(x) = xsin$(\frac{\pi}{2x})$, x$\in(0,1]$. Consider the sequence
>   $(x_i) = \frac{1}{2n - (i-1)}$, i = 1,...,2n. 
> Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$ diverges as n goes to infinity.

This is what I have so far:

\begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\bigr|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})\bigr| &= \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|\frac{\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi(2n - i + 1)}{2}\right)}{2n - i + 1} - \frac{\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi(2n - i + 2)}{2}\right)}{2n - i + 2}\right|
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|\frac{\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi(2n + 1)}{2}\right)\text{cos}\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)}{2n - i + 1} - \frac{\text{cos}\left(\pi(n + 1)\right)\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)}{2n - i + 2}\right|
\\ &\ge \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left( \left|\frac{\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi(2n + 1)}{2}\right)\text{cos}\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)}{2n - i + 1}\right| - \left|\frac{\text{cos}\left(\pi(n + 1)\right)\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)}{2n - i + 2}\right|\right)
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left(\frac{|\text{cos}(\frac{\pi i}{2})|}{2n - i + 1}-\frac{|\text{sin}(\frac{\pi i}{2})|}{2n - i + 2}\right)
\end{align*}

Based off a hint, I'm trying to express the sum as a harmonic sum but I think I hit a dead end.

Comment: maybe splitting into $i$ even or odd helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index change is very useful. By reversing the order of summation,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})\right| = \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|f(x_{2n+1-i})-f(x_{2n-i})\right| = \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|\,f\left(\frac{1}{i}\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{i+1}\right)\right|$$
and by setting $g(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ we have that the previous sum equals:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|g(i)-g(i+1)\right|=|g(1)|+2|g(3)|+2|g(5)|+\ldots+2|g(2n-1)|+|g(2n+1)| $$
since for any even integer $x$ we have that $g(x)$ is just zero. That leads to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\left|g(i)-g(i+1)\right|=1+\frac{1}{2n+1}+2\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}&\geq& 1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\log\frac{k+1}{k}\\ &=& 1+\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
so the sum is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series, as suspected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $i$ is even we have $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi\left(2n-i+2\right)}{2}\right)=0,\,\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi\left(2n-i+1\right)}{2}\right)=\pm1$$ and if $i$ is odd we have $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi\left(2n-i+2\right)}{2}\right)=\pm1,\,\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi\left(2n-i+1\right)}{2}\right)=0.$$